# Netbeans: Auto-replace emtpy with empty

Tags: netbeans

I'm doing a lot of php-programming in Netbeans. It occurs like at least once a day that I write emtpy instead of empty (dunno why). Costs me each time at least 15s to test, see and find the mistake and correcting it (and I'm really annoyed each time).

Is there an option to automatically replace every emtpy with empty or at least highlighting it (like with big fat flashy arrows? :P)

Couldn't find anything of the sort with a quick search.

Thanks for any suggestion!

P.S.: I want it to be like in Word, when you type the first two characters in CApital it will auto replace it by only the first letter Capital. Please see comments as well, before replying.

Comment: it is not regarding `PHP`.

Comment: Goto Edit->Replace In Project-> and write emtpy in containing text and write empty in replace with. And browse your project in which you want replace.

Comment: That does not really help. I FIND those mistakes and correct them. It's in live programming, where it is really annoying that every time I make this mistake have to switch windows press F5 wait, see and understand that I've made that mistake, switch back, find the line, correct it, press Cltr+S, switch back windows, Press F5...
It does not help to run Replace in Project every time. Is about the same time it takes.

Comment: What would help on the other hand; If I had one keyboard-shortcut to run it as some kind of Makro. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

No a real solution but maybe an improvement of your situation:

You could (mis)use a code template for that: Tools / Options / Editor / Code Templates. Select your language and create a new abbreviation (empyt) and as "expanded text" you use "empty". Make sure to set "Expand Template on" to "Space".
Drawback is, that it only works if you are pressing space after typing "empty" or "empyt".

Comment: I thought of that too. Unfortunately you usually don't use any of those keys afterwards... But better than nothing.